# CSS: Fixed content con columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the **columns** css property to create two columns for a faq-type page. On that page when you click a FAQ question, the answer expands/collapses. This code behaves exactly like what I'm working with. The code is the following:

```js
    function toggleFAQ(_Target) {
      if(document.getElementById(_Target).className == "faq-hidden")
        document.getElementById(_Target).className = "";
      else
        document.getElementById(_Target).className = "faq-hidden";
    }
```

```css
 .faq-columns {
      -webkit-columns: 2 400px;
      -moz-columns: 2 400px;
      columns: 2 400px;
    }
    .faq-wrapper {
      -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
      page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
      break-inside: avoid-column;         /* IE 11 */
      display:table;                      /* Actually FF 20+ */
    }
    .faq-hidden {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
   <h3>FAQ Topic</h3>
    <p>Description of this topic.</p>
    
    <div class="faq-columns">
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq1')">FAQ One</h4>
        <p id="faq1" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq2')">FAQ Two</h4>
        <p id="faq2" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq3')">FAQ Three</h4>
        <p id="faq3" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq4')">FAQ Four</h4>
        <p id="faq4" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq5')">FAQ Five</h4>
        <p id="faq5" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq6')">FAQ Six</h4>
        <p id="faq6" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq7')">FAQ Seven</h4>
        <p id="faq7" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-wrapper">
        <h4 onclick="toggleFAQ('faq8')">FAQ Eight</h4>
        <p id="faq8" class="faq-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So, on to the question. As you may see, if you click a column, because of the new height, an element from it flows to *the other column*. I'd like to **prevent this** from happening, and have the contents of each column stick with that column no matter its height.

I've searched for this but couldn't manage to find anyone with the same problem.

Thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: You can't force things to be in specific columns, the nature of css columns is that it will automatically equalise the content based on the available height and the height of it's contents, if that height changes, then the separation may change too.  You would need to set up the columns  manually (ie use some other approach like flex) if you want them to stay in their positions

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was using a different approach before, but I had the problem where if I expanded a column on one side, it would add blank space to its 'matching column' in the other side. So I decided to go with the css columns instead. Now, this would be a totally different question, but of course any hint is welcomed!